# Why to different interface in the same fields compatible in TS

Tags: typescript

I have these 2 interfaces:

```
export interface IProductInCartBody {
  count: number;
  variantId: string;
}

export interface IProductInCart {
  id: string;
  variantId: string;
  name: string;
  price: number;
  count: number;
}
```

Why do I not get an error on this line?

```
const test: IProductInCartBody[] = productsInTheCart as IProductInCart[];
```

I think I tried all)))

Comment: Because anything that can use an IProductInCartBody can also use an IProductInCart - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Comment: [You don't need `as` here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQAUoIATAV2xnyQGFNYAhMgTzgG8AoOObCclAC44ScgFsARmgDc3OADcGCTCnylhAZxhRkAc1kBfTp1CRYiFGiy4CxMpWp0G8LjwTq4WnUn1zFOlWoPLz1ZHiRMMWBNbVC5MB1cYVFJGTk+ARhk8SkoQ2M+JC04dAgIYSISCioaelgAbQBdOABeOHr2RA8AckxugBoFJUC1YW6JAZFI6Lhu7EmEhCS4AEZBjKFVuANG2ULiiQYKu2rHOphmUhYm1pKy2U4gA).

Comment: ...but even with it, don't forget what type casting does: it is *you the programmer* asserting to *the compiler* that a value is a certain type for reasons the compiler cannot prove. If you tell the compiler "shut up, I know what I'm doing" then it's going to do that rather than complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get an error in that line is because TypeScript allows you to perform type assertions in certain cases, even when the types are not exactly the same.
 In this specific case, the type assertion `productsInTheCart` as `IProductInCart[]` is telling TypeScript to treat the `productsInTheCart` variable as an array of `IProductInCart` objects, even though its declared type is `IProductInCartBody[]`.

TypeScript allows this type assertion because `IProductInCartBody` has a subset of the properties of `IProductInCart`, namely count and variantId.
 When you assign an array of `IProductInCartBody` to a variable of type `IProductInCart[]`, TypeScript infers that each element in the array has at least the properties required by `IProductInCart`.
 The other properties, such as `id`, `name`, and `price`, are not necessary for TypeScript to verify the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Because `IProductInCartBody` defines that an object fulfilling the interface contract has to have a property `count` of type `number` and a propery `variantId` of type `string`.

As ab object of type `IProductInCart` fulfills those two things, it fulfills this contract (= interface) and therefore you can assign the value.

In other words `IProductInCart` is more specific than `IProductInCartBody`. You could also define your interfaces as follows, which makes it easier to understand:

```js
export interface IProductInCartBody {
  count: number;
  variantId: string;
}

export interface IProductInCart extends IProductInCartBody {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  price: number;
}

const productInCart: IProductInCart = {
    id: "1",
    name: "Product 1",
    price: 20,
    count: 2,
    variantId: "1"
}

const productInCartBody: IProductInCartBody = productInCart;
```

See also [TypeScript docs on type compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html).